# What will be the minimum app size of cocos2d-x game?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I am new in cocos2d-x and I would like to do a simple game with textures less than 1MB. But when I build my project, total app size is 9MB.

How can I reduce this. I have removed Box2d and chipmunk references. Still it is 8.5MB.

What will be the minimum size of small games of android and iPhone platforms.

Comment: remove extensions if you don't need them.

Comment: Be sure to compile the release configuration, not the debug, as the executable may be significantly larger in debug builds.

Answer (score 3):

The size pf game varies with cocos2d-x versions.
The minimum game size build via cocos2d-x 3.2 is around 2MB.
for cocos2d-x 3.1.1 is around 1.7MB
for cocos2d-x 3.0 is around 1.5MB
If you do not need to use box2d or chipmunk or integrated Node Physics then you can use cocos2d-x 2.2.5 and its minimum game size is around 1MB

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily a minimum size to a cocos2d-x game. I would also counsel against removing libraries just to meet arbitrary size requirements. A good idea would be to first make your game with the features you want then worry about its size.

Comment: So, I cannot make a simple game with size 3-4 MB using cocos2d-x?

Comment: You would have to strip everything that *can* be stripped. It's unlikely to be a code issue, so check any images, icons, etc. already included by the project. Note that many of them are mandatory.